# Знаки сравнения из string

Tags: c#

Всем привет.Интересна такая вещь,можно ли получить знаки сравнения (> < = >= <=) из string и потом использовать их?

```
public class Main
{

   List<ListItem> ls = new List<ListItem>();
   private void FilterButtonClick(...)
   {
   if(Combobox1.SelectedText == "Id")
   {
       if(Combobox2.Selectedtext == ">=")
       {
       var its = ls.Where(z=>z.Id>=Convert.ToInt32(Textbox1.Text)).ToList();
       for(int i = 0;i<its.Count;i++)
       {
       datagridview.Rows.Add(Its[i].Name);
       }
       else if(Combobox2.Selectedtext == "<=")
       {
       var its = ls.Where(z=>z.Id<=Convert.ToInt32(Textbox1.Text)).ToList();
       for(int i = 0;i<its.Count;i++)
       {
       datagridview.Rows.Add(Its[i].Name);
       }
       }
   }
   else if(Combobox1.SelectedText == "Age")
   {
   if(Combobox2.Selectedtext == ">=")
       {
       var its = ls.Where(z=>z.Age>=Convert.ToInt32(Textbox1.Text)).ToList();
       for(int i = 0;i<its.Count;i++)
       {
       datagridview.Rows.Add(Its[i].Name);
       }
       else if(Combobox2.Selectedtext == "<=")
       {
       var its = ls.Where(z=>z.Age<=Convert.ToInt32(Textbox1.Text)).ToList();
       for(int i = 0;i<its.Count;i++)
       {
       datagridview.Rows.Add(Its[i].Name);
       }
       }
   }
   }

}
public class ListItem
{
string Name;
int Id;
int Age;
int birthday_date;
int Height;
int Weight;
}
```

Знаю код лучше было делать с Switch.Но писал на сайте и так было удобней.

Comment: Например, `switch`?

Comment: По факту возможно.Но это займёт 5 раз больше кода.В моем случае вместо ~100 будет 500 строк.

Comment: А какой тип данных вам нужно сравнивать?

Comment: Int.Нужно сделать фильтр в программе.Более 10 перемення. Планировал так в одном combobox- переменные.Во втором 3 знака сравнения.И textbox,какие значения искать

Comment: думаю, что тут проще уже свой DSL написать

Comment: @ლუკაბერიანიძე А вы можете то, что вы написали в комментарие, перенести в вопрос? А то без него он неясен.

Comment: Щас допишу код в пост.Поможет разобраться).

Comment: Дополнил пост...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, для `int`:

```
Func<int, int, bool> ConstructRelation(string s)
{
    switch (s)
    {
        case ">":  return (Func<int, int, bool>)((a, b) => a > b);
        case "<":  return (Func<int, int, bool>)((a, b) => a < b);
        case "==": return (Func<int, int, bool>)((a, b) => a == b);
        case ">=": return (Func<int, int, bool>)((a, b) => a >= b);
        case "<=": return (Func<int, int, bool>)((a, b) => a <= b);
        default: throw new ArgumentException("Unknown relation");
    }
}
```

Пользоваться так:

```
Func<int, int, bool> rel = ConstructRelation(">");
Console.WriteLine(rel(5, 4)); // выводит True
```

Рабочий код: http://ideone.com/UWgKlU

---

Пользоваться можно примерно так:

```
Func<ListItem, int> firstGetter = null;
switch (Combobox1.SelectedText)
{
    case "Id": firstGetter = z => z.Id; break;
    case "Age": firstGetter = z => z.Age; break;
    // тут остальные значения
    default: throw new ArgumentException();
}

int secondValue = Convert.ToInt32(Textbox1.Text);

Func<int, int, bool> rel = ConstructRelation(Combobox2.Selectedtext);

var its = ls.Where(z => rel(firstGetter(z), secondValue));

foreach(var item in its)
{
    datagridview.Rows.Add(item.Name);
}
```

Comment: Подозреваю такой способ не подойдет,причина в написана в в первом сообщении.

Comment: @ლუკაბერიანიძე: Подойдёт, по идее. Посмотрите обновление ответа.

Comment: Спасибо.Помогло.

Comment: @ლუკა: пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Через [Scripting API](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples#exprstrong):

```
> Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting
```

[пакет с пачкой зависимостей, может долго скачиваться]

И после этого можно собирать код на лету:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;

namespace ConsoleApplication27
{
    public class Globals
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var globals = new Globals { X = 1, Y = 2 };
            string op = ">";
            Console.WriteLine(CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<bool>($"X{op}Y", globals: globals).Result);
        }
    }
}
```

При реальном использовании стоит добавить кэширование и принудительную компиляцию через `Compile()` + `RunAsync` вместо `EvaluateAsync`.

---

Для трех знаков сравнения это как из пушки по воробьям. Если объектов мало - то самый простой вариант - switch по знакам сравнения + reflection для извлечения свойства по имени. Дешево, сердито и читабельно.

Если объектов много - то можно пропробовать собрать лямбду для сравнения на лету:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication27
{
    class ListItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static readonly Dictionary<string, ExpressionType> opsMap =
            new Dictionary<string, ExpressionType>
            {
                {  ">=", ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual },
                {  "==", ExpressionType.Equal },
                {  "<=", ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual }
            };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string operation = ">=";
            string fieldToCompare = "Age";
            string textToCompare = "15";
            List<ListItem> ls = new List<ListItem>
            {
                new ListItem { Age = 10, Name = "a" },
                new ListItem { Age = 20, Name = "b" },
            };

            var listItemType = typeof(ListItem);
            var propToCompare = listItemType.GetProperty(fieldToCompare);

            var valueToCompare = Convert.ChangeType(textToCompare, propToCompare.PropertyType);

            // собираем лямбду x => x.Age >= 15
            var param = Expression.Parameter(listItemType);
            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<ListItem, bool>>(
                Expression.MakeBinary(opsMap[operation],
                    Expression.Property(param, propToCompare),
                    Expression.Constant(valueToCompare)),
                param); // .Compile и кэш при необходимости

            // убрать AsQueryable если выше используется Compile
            var result = ls.AsQueryable().Where(predicate).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ого, в .NET появился простой скриптинг, круто.